How to Connect to a Socks5 Proxy with Auth in Selenium?
I need to connect ChromeDriver to a socks5 proxy with authentication, but Chrome doesn't support it. So is there a way to create a sort of interceptor that will redirect all requests to my socks5 proxy?
I tried to implement a local proxy server which would create an HTTP proxy server on some port and redirect all requests to socks5. But it takes too much time to accomplish this.
I need this in my c# app, so I don't really like the idea of running separately some third-party server on a PC.
